# Creating Derived Class with Given Base Class

Tags: c#

If I have this:

```
public class bClass
{
    int id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
}

public class dClass : bClass
{
    int extraVal {get; set;}
}
```

and I have a list of bClass objects:

```
List<bClass> baseClassList = getBaseClassList();
```

what is the easiest way to convert the baseClassList to a list of dClass objects with "extralVal" set as a specified value? I would hope for a solution something like:

```
public class dClass : bClass
{
    public dClass(bClass b, int exVal)
    {
        base = b;
        extraVal = exVal;
    }
    int extraVal {get; set;}
}

List<dClass> dClassList = bClassList.ConvertAll(x => new dClass(x, exVal));
```

where it essentially just plugs in the base and then sets the extra property value, but obviously that is not the right syntax. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can't 'turn' an object into an object of another type, unless you provide a function that takes objects of type A, makes a `new` object of type B and returns it.

Comment: That is what the ConvertAll method is for I thought?

Comment: How can it work `base = b;`?

Comment: It cannot work, that is the part that I'm trying to get the correct syntax for. How do I set the "base" part of a derived class without manually copying over each property?

Comment: @Jordan What I see in given question inheritance is bad choice. You could wrap your base class. Take a look at decorator pattern. Also it would be better if you add some more context to your question (i.e. what is the real-world usage), so we can give you better answer..

Comment: You may find [_automapper_](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) useful but it's slow.

Comment: I second @PLB. Use decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the exact scenario, but projection might help?

```
bClassList.Select(i=>new dClass{ id=i.id, name=i.name, extraval=exVal});
```

Or you can use reflection

```
public dClass(bClass c) 
{ 
// copy base class properties. 
 foreach (PropertyInfo prop in c.GetType().GetProperties()) 
 {   
  PropertyInfo prop2 = c.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name); 
  prop2.SetValue(this,prop.GetValue(c, null), null); 
 }  
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to accomplish, but without having to set each property (id, name) explicitly.

Comment: public dClass(bClass c)
        {
            // copy base class properties.
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in c.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyInfo prop2 = c.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                prop2.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(c, null), null);
            }
        }

Comment: Haha yep, was just in the process of coding this up. Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan Reflection is slow. So before you implement it think how performance critical your application is.

Comment: @bazz Move code from comment in answer for future readers, please. ;)

Comment: stop reflection is slow. you should staticly create a list of properties/fields before hand and than only loop it.

Comment: @NahumLitvin http://ideone.com/CCNFxV I hope this is enough to understand that reflection is much slower. :) OP will get nested loop every-time (s)he creates object in loop.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new object of a derived type based upon an object of the base type.

I think the closest you will get is a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the base-class.

```
public class bClass {
    public bClass(bClass source) {
        // TODO: Null check
        id = source.id;
        name = source.name;
    }

    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}

public class dClass : bClass {
    public dClass(bClass source, int extraVal): base(source) {
        // TODO: Null check
        extraVal = extraVal;
    }

    public int extraVal {get; set;}
}

List<bClass> baseClassList = getBaseClassList();
List<dClass> dClassList = bClassList.ConvertAll(x => new dClass(x, exVal));
```

Comment: Yes, I have done this, but I was just hoping there might be a way to do this without explicitly saying "id=source.id" for each different property. The base class has a LOT of properties, not only 2 like in this abstracted example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to convert a base object into derived one. It is bad practice too. Your current solution is best suited for the situation.

`ConvertAll` is the right function. This is from MSDN.

`Converts an array of one type to an array of another type.`

As @PLB mentioned, you should look into `Decorator Pattern`.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the function I am asking about. I'm trying to figure out how to build a constructor in a derived class that takes a base class object and sets all the properties in the derived class to its values without specifically setting each property.

Comment: You still need a convertor to change the objects from one type in another. And that is the problem, you cannot automatically turn an object of one type into an object of a derived type. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: There is no built-in way to convert a base object into derived one. You would have to implement it yourself or use LINQ as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You still will need constructor which copies all fields to base class. You can place constuctor wich accepts bClass in base class and then call it in child class.

```
bClass
{
    ....
    public bClass(bClass b)
        {
            ...
        }
}

public class dClass : bClass
{
    public dClass(bClass b, int exVal):base(b)
    {
        extraVal = exVal;
    }
....
}
```

and found this link about how to write copy constructor in c# using reflection
http://johnsadventures.com/2006/07/03/an_intelligent_copy_constructor_in_c_usi/

Comment: It's a pity but "C# doesn't provide a copy constructor for objects, but you can write one yourself".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173116.aspx

Comment: and found this link about how to write copy constructor in c# using reflection http://johnsadventures.com/2006/07/03/an_intelligent_copy_constructor_in_c_usi/

Answer (score 0):

A constructor can use the base keyword to call the constructor of a base class. Following is an example:

```
public class Manager : Employee
{
    public Manager(int annualSalary)
        : base(annualSalary)
    {
        //Add further instructions here.
    }
}
```

([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx))